# Can't find '__main__' module when running celery with Django / virtualenv

Tags: python, django, celery, virtualenv, supervisord

Debian 9.8
virtualenv 16.4.3
Python 3.5.3
Django 2.1.7
celery 4.3.0
django-celery-beat 1.4.0

When I run celery commands from my app directory with my venv active like `celery worker -A personnel` or `celery beat -l info --scheduler django_celery_beat.schedulers:DatabaseScheduler`, it works as expected. My app's name is 'personnel'.

There are several related issues but nothing exactly like mine. Here is what happens when I try various commands.

`celery worker` from the project directory with venv active starts the worker and looks as the documentation shows it should (redis is working, beat works as well)

`/home/www/personnel/venv/bin/python` from outside of the proj dir with venv not active drops me into a shell where I can import Celery without errors

`/home/www/personnel/venv/bin/celery` from outside the proj shows me the celery help (usage: celery  [options]...)

`/home/www/personnel/venv/bin/python /home/www/personnel celery worker`, which from my research is what should be working, returns:
`/home/www/personnel/venv/bin/python: can't find '__main__' module in '/home/www/personnel'`

The above error is returned even with the -A flag.

`/home/www/personnel/venv/bin/python /home/www/personnel/manage.py celery worker` returns:

```
Unknown command: 'celery'
Type 'manage.py help' for usage.
```

The stdout log shows the same errors. I am guessing the command should work before supervisor comes into play.

I have started from scratch and recreated the venv with the same result.

```
# __init__.py
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
from .celery import app as celery_app

__all__ = ['celery_app']
```

```
# celery.py
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import os
from celery import Celery
#from celery.schedules import crontab

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'personnel.settings')

app = Celery('personnel')
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
app.autodiscover_tasks()


@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))
```

```
; ==================================
; celery worker config
; ==================================

[program:celery]
; full path using virtualenv
command=/home/www/personnel/venv/bin/python /home/www/personnel celery worker -A personnel -I info

directory=/home/www/personnel
;user=dunnoyet
numprocs=1
stderr_logfile=/var/log/celery.out.log
stdout_logfile=/var/log/celery.err.log
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startsecs=10

; need to wait for currently executing tasks to finish at shutdown
; increase if long running tasks
stopwaitsecs = 600

; send the termination signal (SIGTERM) to the whole process group
stopasgroup=true

; set Celery priority higher than default (999)
; so, if rabbitmq is supervised, it will start first
priority=1000
```

```
# Project structure based on django cookie cutter
pr_project
|--personnel
   |--api/
   |--...
   |--__init__.py
   |--celery.py
   |--urls.py
   |--views.py
   |--wsgi.py
|--requirements
|--...
```

From the project directory it works as expected but I cannot get it to work outside or start successfully with supervisor.

**edit**

```
#personnel/settings.py
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://localhost:6379'
```

As suggested I tried `/home/www/personnel/venv/bin/celery worker` - it starts, but looks like it cannot connect to redis

```
[2019-04-05 09:18:11,960: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//: [Errno 111] Connection refused.
```

With app flag `/home/www/personnel/venv/bin/celery worker -A personnel`:

```
Error:
Unable to load celery application.
The module personnel was not found.
```

Comment: I don't understand the command you are trying. Why not just `/home/www/personnel/venv/bin/celery worker`?

Comment: Or `/home/www/personnel/venv/bin/python celery worker`? Basically I don't see why you have added that extra `/home/www/personnel`.

Comment: @DanielRoseman ha likely just because I just don't understand enough about how things work :( just trying what I have found in suggestions while googling it. I will add results as an edit up top

Answer (score 0):

When using supervisor, it works with:

```
[program:celery]
; full path using virtualenv
command=/home/www/personnel celery worker

directory=/home/www/personnel
```

It won't work when trying from the command line, perhaps since it needs the Django settings accessible.